# How to trigger the horizontal scroll event by touch on mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, .net-4.5

I'm working with an emulator to simulate a hand held smart phone. Every thing is working fine with the structure of the DOM.

When testing on a true device I can touch the screen and scroll up and down, but I cannot get the screen to scroll left or right.

I've included a snapshot of the what I'm talking about below. I need to be able to scroll the overflow content from the right side over to the viewport so the user can see that portion of the screen.

***Overlook the scrollbar on the far right side that is from the iframe that is in the emulator and does not show up on a true hand held.

Again: What is the setting so that the user can scroll the overflown content into view horizontally?

[image: Snap shot of emulator]

Comment: Are you asking us how to make this (unnamed) emulator scroll horizontally?

Comment: I'm asking you how to make a real life hand held device scroll left and right by touching the screen and moving the content into view. The name of the emulator is Ripple, and I can scroll left and right by using the emulator, but when I set the mobile site into production it will only scroll up and down and not left to right.

Comment: On a real smartphone, you swipe left and right. Unless there's nothing over there, in which case nothing will happen.

Comment: That's what I thought but clearly looking at the snap shot there is content overflown to the right and I need to get that content over to the left by touch.

Comment: Can't you provide us with some actual code, or a functioning example, or both?

Comment: I was able to track down the issue, in the jquery file this class property was set to .ui-page-active {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    } So I changed it to     .ui-page-active {
        overflow-x: visible !important;
    }